# Codeigniter: passing session userdata from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter, variables

So this is a small problem, but after research still can't make this work. I want to pass "username" variable from session user data. From my controller to view. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    function members_area()
{
    $user['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['main_content'] = 'members_area';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data, $user);
}
```

And in view I use this:

```
<?php echo "$username" ?>
```

EDIT: I solved it in a more simple way. Because session userdata is available global in every page while user is logged in, there is no need to pass it like this.

I just made this line in my view page:

```
<?php echo $name = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `$this->load->view` is True or False - not another variable.

[The Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) provides a fantastic overview of how views work.

Do this:

```
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

And then in the view:

```
<?php echo $username; ?>
```

You might also consider using a real templating plugin for CodeIgniter, if you plan to use a template.

Good luck!

Comment: ok, this way doesn't worked for me somehow, so I made it work in other way, changing $this line to $this->load->view('members_area', $user); but I can't get all my style of page this way

Comment: Read the link I posted, and then read about templating plugins. It will make your life much easier with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to populate only `$data`:

```
// Controller
function members_area()
{
  $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
  $data['main_content'] = 'members_area';
  $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

// View
<?= $username ?>
```